# How to upload webpage with image?

Tags: html

As a homework, I have to create my own webpage, but I can’t upload without any changes. Every time I try to hand in, link is disconnected, and image doesn’t show. I tried  to make webpage and image one folder, and I could see it in my computer, but didn’t work for other computer.
In this case, do I have to upload to Internet? Here is the webpage where I have to submit webpage.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGa2C.png)

Comment: add your code to understand it better

Answer (score 2):

Aren't there any submission guidelines provided? In general though, you'd be asked to zip your HTML code and your images in one folder, and submit the zip. Better to ask your professor though.

Comment: @Kouji glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/marking as answer. Have a good day!